# How do I configure Spring to use my factory when instantiating POJOs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Person class is a simple POJO with 2 fields:

```
String name
String role
```

My `@Configuration` annotated class includes

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "people")
public List<Person> people() {
    return new ArrayList()
}
```

and the yaml configuration file

```
people:
  - name: Maria
    role: Buyer
  - name: Ana
    role: Seller
  - name: Patrik
    role: Buyer
```

and when I `@Autowire` people I magically get a `List<People>` with 3 elements and all fields correctly set.

This is brilliant!

But now I want to control how Person is instantiated so that I have 2 implementations `Buyer` and `Seller` based on the role string. I would do that by using some sort of factory but unsure how to wire my factory with Spring.

Note: implementing the factory itself is assumed knowledge, I just want to know how to configure Spring to use my factory when instantiating `Person`.

Comment: well loading them from database can be better option.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas people was just an example here. Actual type is irrelevant but in my case not something that could live in a database e.g. some transformation steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following classes:

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();

    /**
     * @return role retrieved from configuration or else
     * {@code null} if used in extensions
     */
    default String getRole() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Buyer implements Person {
    private String name;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Seller implements Person {
    private String name;
}
```

And then use them like:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "people")
public Set<Buyer> buyers() {
    return new ArrayList<Person>()
            .stream()
            .filter(person -> "Buyer".equals(person.getRole()))
            .map(person -> new Buyer(person.getName()))
            .collect(toSet());

}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "people")
public Set<Seller> sellers() {
    return new ArrayList<Person>()
            .stream()
            .filter(person -> "Seller".equals(person.getRole()))
            .map(person -> new Seller(person.getName()))
            .collect(toSet());

}
```

**WARNING:** I have not tested this approach and it is possible that configuration properties are not resolved. If so just make your own configuration properties object:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PeopleConfigurationProperties {

    private List<Person> people;

}
```

And use these like:

```
@Bean
public Set<Seller> buyers(PeopleConfigurationProperties properties) {
    return properties.getPeople()
            .stream()
            .filter(person -> "Seller".equals(person.getRole()))
            .map(person -> new Seller(person.getName()))
            .collect(toSet());
}
```

All of the examples have not been tested, so sorry if any typos or inaccurates are present. Hope this helps